# How to fix validator from firing on all items in ListView

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am trying to have a validator set up to only fire on the item(car in this instance) that the user wants to add to his or her cart. I am using ListView to display the cars I have for sale. When the user selects the car they want and enters in the quantity, the validators fire for every entry. How would I fix this?

Thank you!!

## Cars.apx

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="div2" runat="server">
    <div class="row">
        <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" class="custom-class" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnItemCommand="ListView1_ItemCommand" DataKeyNames="CarID" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="custom_class">
                        <a href='/Shop/Order/<%# Eval("CarID") %>'>
                            <img src='/Images/<%# Eval("ImageCar") %>'
                                alt='<%# Eval("Name") %>' /></a>
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h3>
                                <%# Eval("Name") %>
                            </h3>
                            <p>
                                <b>Price: <%# Eval("CarPrice", "{0:c}") %></b>
                                <br>
                                <br>
                                <%# Eval("Long_Description") %>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-1">Quantity:</label>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" CssClass="text-danger"
                                runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtQuantity1" Display="Dynamic"
                                ErrorMessage="Quantity is a required field."></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator1" runat="server" CssClass="text-danger"
                                ControlToValidate="txtQuantity1" Display="Dynamic"
                                ErrorMessage="Quantity must range from 0 to 2."
                                MaximumValue="2" MinimumValue="0" Type="Integer"></asp:RangeValidator>

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity1" runat="server"
                                CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add to Cart"
                                        OnClick="btnAdd_Click" CssClass="btn" />
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnCart" runat="server" Text="Go to Cart"
                                        PostBackUrl="~/BuyCars.aspx" CausesValidation="False" CssClass="btn" />


                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" EnableViewState="false"
                                CssClass="text-info col-sm-12"></asp:Label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity1" runat="server"
                CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
    </div>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT [CarID], [Name], [Long_Description], [CarPrice], [ImageCar] FROM [Table] ORDER BY [Name]" OnSelecting="SqlDataSource1_Selecting"></asp:SqlDataSource>
</asp:Content>
```

## Cars.apsc.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;

namespace CarSales_REAL
{
    public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {         
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UnobtrusiveValidationMode = UnobtrusiveValidationMode.None;
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                ListView1.DataBind();
            }            
        }            

        private Product GetSelectedProduct(object id)
        {
            DataView productsTable = (DataView)
                SqlDataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
            //productsTable.RowFilter = "CarID = '" + ListView1.SelectedValue + "'";
            DataRowView row = productsTable[1];

            Product p = new Product();
            p.CarID = row["CarID"].ToString();
            p.Name = row["Name"].ToString();
            //p.Short_Description = row["Short_Description"].ToString();
            p.Long_description = row["long_Description"].ToString();
            p.CarPrice = (decimal)row["CarPrice"];
            //p.ImageFile = row["ImageFile"].ToString();
            return p;
        }

        protected void SqlDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
        {            

        }            

        protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Page.IsValid)
            {
                var product = GetSelectedProduct(ListView1.SelectedValue);

                CartItemList cart = CartItemList.GetCart();
                CartItem cartItem = cart[product.CarID];

                if (cartItem == null)
                {
                    cart.AddItem(product,
                                    Convert.ToInt32(txtQuantity1.Text));
                }
                else
                {
                    cartItem.AddQuantity(Convert.ToInt32(txtQuantity1.Text));
                }
                Response.Redirect("BuyCars.aspx");

            }
        }            

        protected void btnCart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void ListView1_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to create a unique `ValidationGroup` per Item. You can use The `ClientID` of the ListView for that along with the `DataItemIndex`. See the snippet for a siple demo.

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
            ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" 
            ValidationGroup='<%# ListView1.ClientID + "_" + Container.DataItemIndex %>'></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" 
            ValidationGroup='<%# ListView1.ClientID + "_" + Container.DataItemIndex %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```